# The converse of the absolute value of a limit

Tags: limits

What functions disprove the following statement?

If the  $\lim_{x\to c}|f(x)|= |L|$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)= L$

Comment: What about an appropriate constant function?

Comment: Think negative numbers.

Comment: Any function with a jump discontinuity at $\;x=0\;$ and continuous everywhere else gives a good, easy example with $\;c=0\;$ . Say: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\;\;\;1\;,\;\;x\ge 0\\-1\;,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Absolute value is not bijective... What is $|L|$? if $L$ has not been introduced before...

Answer (score 3):

The limit of $f(x)$ can be $\pm L$ or fail to exist. For the last case consider for example $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=-1$ if $x$ is irrational.